# I am having trouble running slither and mythril on contracts that import more than 1 library

Tags: solidity, slither, mythril

I'm trying to audit some of the damn vulnerable defi challenges using static analyzers slither and mythril. I can run these tools on the challenges that use the openzeppelin library exclusively thanks to the remapping. However, I am not being able to remap more than 1 library(uniswap and gnosis for the puppet-v2 and backdoor challenges respectively). If you have any suggestions, please go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

To use static analysis tools like Slither and Mythril to audit contracts that use multiple libraries, you can use the --remap flag to specify multiple libraries and their corresponding file paths. For example, if you are using Slither to audit a contract that uses both the Uniswap and Gnosis libraries, you can use the following command:

```
slither --remap Uniswap:/path/to/uniswap.sol,Gnosis:/path/to/gnosis.sol /path/to/contract.sol
```

This will tell Slither to use the files uniswap.sol and gnosis.sol as the source code for the Uniswap and Gnosis libraries, respectively, when analyzing the contract at /path/to/contract.sol.

You can use a similar approach with Mythril by using the --remap flag in a similar way.